# Django: How can I remove all stored messages?

Tags: django, django-messages

I used `django message framework` only in one `view`(`PasswordChangeView`).

Problem is that when I access to `PasswordChangeView`, this page shows all message in message storage such as `Login successed, Logout success` etc...

This is my `template.html`:

```
{% for message in messages %}
    <p {% if message.tags %} class="alert alert-{{ message.tags }} messages"{% endif %}> {{ message }} </p>
{% endfor %}
```

I want to make `PasswordChangeView` show message only about `password`, not `login, logout` kinda thing.

How can I do this?

Comment: [use extra message tags](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.10/ref/contrib/messages/#adding-extra-message-tags)

Comment: Why are you creating messages for your login/logout views if you're not showing them anywhere else? If you'd show them they wouldn't pop up the moment you access the `PasswordChangeView`.

Comment: @Bono oh cuz I used `django-allauth` and it shows messages automatically.

Answer (score 1):

**One way** is to create 2 empty files `templates/account/messages/logged_in.txt` and `templates/account/messages/logged_out.txt`

It basically overwrites the login/logout messages.

**Another way** is to check in the template, such as:

```
--- Your code ---
{% if "signed" in message|safe %} 
  # Don't display anything
{% else %}
--- Your remaining code ---
```